# VBA: Edit legend names from excel chart using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have made a chart where I try to plot some specific data. For that purpose I made this code:

```
Sub plotsim()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim chrt As Chart
worksh = Application.Sheets.Count
Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Simulation")
Set chrt = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
With chrt
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Portfolio forecast"""
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets("Simulation").Range("A2:A" & fsize + 1)
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Sheets("Simulation").Range(Sheets("Simulation").Cells(2, worksh + 1), Sheets("Simulation").Cells(fsize + 1, worksh + 1))
End With
End Sub
```

But once I take a look at the chart, what I see is a legend with two different lines.
[image]

How can I remove (or edit) the *Series2* title?

Comment: AFAIK you can click in to the chart, then click again the legend, and select "Series2" only, then just press the `DELETE` key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really wanted to edit *Series2* in the legend you would change it the same manner you changed the name of Series1:

```
.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Unwanted series"
```

[image]

---

**Note**: I had originally answered with the following:

> The following line of code is adding your unwanted *Series2*:
>
> ```
> .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
> ```
>
> Simply remove it.

But I see now that it was not entirely correct. Sometimes an additional one is created, sometimes not, depending on what has happened in the past on the sheet (I think I'm missing something obvious). I've been able to reproduce both behaviors. If you somehow end up with additional series', you could remove any superfluous ones with a call to:

```
.SeriesCollection(2).Delete
```

so long as you use the correct series number. You could include a test like this to see if an extra one has been made:

```
If .SeriesCollection.Count > 1 then .SeriesCollection(2).Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but I post this for others who are wondering. The question asked was how to *remove or edit the series title*. Now, it seems OP got what he wanted by deleting the entire series. But sometimes we want to keep the series, but don't show it in the legend. To delete a series from the legend, but keep the series in the chart, you do this:

```
[Chart name].Legend.LegendEntires([Variable name]).Delete
```

If you want to change the legend name for a certain variable, you do this:

```
[Chart name].Legend.LegendEntires([Variable name]).Name = [Your prefered variable name]
```